# Creating Variant Articles

Tags: php, mysql, api, magento

I'm just working on an Import of Configurable Products.
The Parent is created and the Children accordingly to my CRM and MAgento System Correct (Data etc).
The only part that is missing are the direct connections between the parent articles and the children articles (the links are basicly missing).

Here is the code that does the linking:

```
$resultArray = array();
foreach($this - > variant as $variantsArray) {
    foreach($variantsArray as $variantArray) {
        $resultArray[$variantArray['id']] = array();
        array_push(
            $resultArray[$variantArray['id']],
            array(
                "attribute_id" = > $variantArray['attr_id'],
                "label" = > $variantArray['label'],
                "is_percent" = > false,
                "pricing_value" = > $variantArray['price']
            )
        );
    }
}
$this-> product->setConfigurableProductsData($resultArray);
```

The Data in variant looks like this:

```
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 205
                [price] => 12
                [attr_code] => color
                [attr_id] => 92
                [value] => 13
                [label] => taupe
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 206
                [price] => 13
                [attr_code] => color
                [attr_id] => 92
                [value] => 11
                [label] => hellgrau
            )

    )

)
```

This is basicly only a real simple example as I need to create Variants that have following options:

Child 1: Size XXL Color red

Child 2: Size M Color red

Child 3: Size XXL Color green

So not all options are available in all combinations.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my issue.
Everything is set correct except the properties in the child articles.
after adding this, everything works correct.